# Number of roots for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies the following conditions:

$$f(0)=0,$$
$$f'(x)\neq0 \ \text{for any } \{x: f(x)=0\}.$$

What is the necessary and sufficient condition for $\exists \epsilon$ such that $f(x)$ has no root on the interval $(0,\epsilon)$?

---

*Claim 1:* Continuity is not a sufficient condition.

*Claim 2:* Almost everywhere differentiablity of $f$ is not sufficient

*Claim 3:* Absolute continuity is sufficient

For the *Claim 1*, at a first glance, continuity seems sufficient: since $f'(x)\neq 0$, $\{x|f(x)=0\}$ is a discrete set; we then pick the root next to $0$, denote it as $\epsilon$. However, without countability, the operation of "pick the next point" does not make sense. In fact, let $f$ be a Weierstrass function, it is possible that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $f(x)$ has uncountable many roots on $(0,\epsilon)$.

For the *Claim 2*, it is still possible that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $f(x)$ has roots on $(0,\epsilon)$.

Not sure about *Claim 3*, though...

I think $f$ being differentiable is sufficient but not necessary.

---

It fine to interpret $f'(0)\neq 0$ as $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$; any intuition on this $f(0)$ differentiable case will be a good answer. Though I was more interested in another case: $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$ and the subderivative $f'(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: Claim 3 is easy after your edit. We have $f(0)=0$ so $f'(0)$ exists and is nonzero. An interval $(0,r)$ where $f\ne 0$ then follows immediately.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for your comments! If Claim 3 is easy, then how is Claim 2 different? I edited for readability and to make one of answers work. Unfortunately he deleted his results.

Comment: I thought his argument that the set $\{f(x)|f'(x)=0\}$ is countable (Sard theorem?) was very exciting.

Comment: Your edit changed the problem a lot. It seems trivial now. And now you write "$f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$ and the subderivative $f'(0)\neq 0$." What does that mean?